# Using alias name instead of field name in GetFeatureInfo in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, json, getfeatureinfo, alias

I've created a Leaflet map and use `GetFeatureInfo` to send request to GeoServer. Everything is ok but I want to use Alias field name instead of field name. Indeed I want to replace real field with alias name when GeoServer is creating the return JSON file.

Is there any way to handle this issue?

Comment: Is it your geoserver WMS service

Comment: yes it is my geoserver WMS service.

Answer (score 1):

From GeoServer 2.21 there is an option, in "Edit Layer > Feature Type Details", to "Customize attributes" and set field aliases (`Name`) instead of the physical field name (`Source`).